# Set Post Thumbnail to external URL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images, scripts

This question is with regard to feature images on WooCommerce `product` post types, however it should probably apply to any post type.

I am running a custom script to create new posts (of type `product`) and want to set the featured image to be an external URL, rather than importing the images to my server as the images are already served via CDNs.

A normal featured image sets `_thumbnail_id` in the `wp_postmeta` table, and the `meta_value` column then references the image details on `wp_posts`. Whilst I can probably manually create these database entries, I am wondering if there is a WordPress function to do this that I don't know about.

I'm looking for a programatic solution rather than any plugin suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is a workaround I have used in the past. Rather than set the featured image, how about creating a custom field like `external-image-source`?  Then modify the template to use this URL if present.

Comment: Thanks @jdm2112 - I was going to use that as a fallback as I'm using ACF for other product data. Was just hoping there was a WooCommerce `set_featured_image_url` or similar but can't see one in the [WC_Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) or [WC_Product_External](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_External.html) docs